# Which word in Russian has the longest consonant cluster?

Tags: лексикон, согласные

I've heard about this word

> контрвзбзднуть

which has 9 consonants in a row. Obviously this word doesn't exist. Which *real* word(s) has the longest consonant cluster?

Comment: You just made my day with this word :)))) +1

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Let's face the truth: we're all from Stack Overflow here.

```
$ egrep '[бвгджзклмнпрстфхцчшщ]{6,}' lopatin.txt

адъюнктство, —а
попразднство, —а
предпразднство, —а
```

Comment: Why not include ь?

Comment: I'm not from Stack Overflow. :P

Comment: @Armen: it's not a consonant. Historically, it's a vowel, currently, it's a modifier. Including `ь` and `ъ` additionally yields `фольксштурм` (and derived words) and `юрисконсультство`.

Comment: @Quassnoi: If we found a word with 8 consecutive consonants including ь, we'd know it has 7 consecutive consonant sounds. ъ is useless here because it can appear only after prefixes before yotated vowels

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan: This would lead us too far away into amazing world of phonology controversies. How many consecutive consonant sounds are in words `разом` and `Эразм` and why?

Comment: @Quassnoi: I pronounce them differently. I pronounce a shwa in разом, and don't pronounce anything between р and м in Эразм

Comment: @Armen: most Russians pronounce a shwa in both words.

Comment: @Quassnoi: I suppose you mean all words ending in зм. I do not agree that *most* Russians pronounce a shwa between these consonants. Of course, some do, but it's not that difficult a cluster, so many don't.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan: that's exactly what I meant by phonology controversies :)

Comment: @Quassnoi But the schwa is not a consonant, it's still a vowel sound, isn't it?

Comment: @Alenanno: Indeed, and if it's there, it breaks the consonant cluster :)

Comment: @Alenanno: of course, but if we count sounds and not letters we should define what to count, and it's not that easy. There are several translations of William Blake's "Tiger" into Russian, one of them reads: *Тигр, о тигр, светло горящий*, and another one: *Тигр, тигр, жгучий страх*. The first reading forbids a schwa between the consonants, the second one requires it.

Comment: Quassnoi, It's an amazingly nice method that you've used! That's what should be called mathematical linguistics :) Could you just try with 8 consonants while allowing *ь* please?

Comment: @texnic: `{6,}` means "six or more".

Comment: nobody asked so... where did you get lopatin.txt and what is it?

Answer (score 3):

With 5 consonants in a row, I'd say:

- **[контрпример](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80)**, *kontrprimer* (counterexample).
- **контрпредложение**, *kontrpredlozhenie* (counteroffer).
- **контрпривод**, *kontrprivod* (countershaft).
- **контрприказ**, *kontrprikaz* (countermand).

(taken from the dictionary)

Comment: Контрстрайк (Counter-Strike) has 6 consonants! Sorry, just kidding :)

Comment: @RomanYankovsky Uhm, we don't consider that a word, right? :D

Comment: The corpus knows the word `контрстратегия`.

Comment: @Alenanno sure :)